# Как сконвертировать строку в дату время?

Tags: python, строки, дата, datetime

```
def main():
    with open('data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as File:  
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        for pdata_row in reader:
            pdata = pdata_row[0]
            pdata_form = pdata[3:].replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").strptime(pdata_form, '%Y-%m-%d')
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Помогите разобраться с `.strptime(pdata_form, '%Y-%m-%d')`
Нужно строковую дату(27.9.1991) отформатировать и привести к `datetime` в чем не точность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, Вам поможет такой код:

```
from datetime import datetime

oldformat = '27.9.1991'
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%d.%m.%Y') #формат даты
newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (newformat)
```

Для примера привела полученную дату к другому виду: ГГГГ-ММ-ДД

Вывод:

`1991-09-27`

Comment: `oldformat = pdata_form`  возникло исключение module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Хм, а у меня работает без ошибок... А `pdata_form` тут почему?

Comment: @dog3000, импортируйте `datetime` как указано в ответе и ошибок не будет)

Comment: @Анастасия В `pdata_form` хранится очищенная дата '27.9.1991' в str